# An isomorphic map from $U(3) \times U(5)$ to $U(15)$

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to show that $U(3) \times U(5)$ is isomorphic to $U(15)$.

Normally,  to prove that two groups are isomorphic to each other I find an isomorphic map that maps the two groups.

I know that $U(3) \times U(5) \cong U(15)$ from googling, but I don't know how to prove it.

> Does anyone know of an isomorphic map that maps these groups?

Comment: You know that $\mathbb{Z_3} \times \mathbb{Z_5} \cong \mathbb{Z_{15}}$...

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: Could you say what you don't understand ? The notations ? Have you heard of the fundamental theorem for finite abelian groups ?

Comment: Have you build explicitly $U(15)$ and $U(3) \times U(5)$ ? Can you show it ?

Comment: See the paragraph "inverses" in (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups)

Comment: the map is $U(15) \rightarrow U(3) \times U(5) : n \mapsto (n \bmod 3, n \bmod 5)$.

Comment: I have not heard of the fundamental theorem for finite abelian groups.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments by @MarcBogaerts, the map is $$\begin{align}
\varphi: U(15)&\to U(3)\times U(5) \\
n&\mapsto (n \bmod{3}, n\bmod{5}).
\end{align}$$

Another way to look at this is through the lens of the Fundamental Theorem of Abelian Groups, noting that

> **Lemma**: $\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb Z_n)\cong U(n)$ for all $n\in\Bbb N\setminus\{0\}$.

---

To learn more, see, for example, Gallian's *Contemporary Abstract Algebra* for a proof of both the fundamental theorem and of the lemma above.

Answer (score 1):

The direct map is
$$\begin{align}
U(3)\times U(5) &\to U(15)  \\
(a \bmod 3,b \bmod 5) &\mapsto 6b-5a\bmod{15}).
\end{align}$$

It is given by the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Existence_(constructive_proof)).

If you want to check this map directly, start by proving that it is well defined.